# tvos how to prevent AVPlayerViewController from gaining focus

Tags: swift, focus, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

Is there a way to prevent the AVPlayerViewController on tvOS from gaining focus?

Since we cannot overreide and implement it as a view controller or a delegate then it is not possible to implement canBecomeFocused or shouldUpdateFocusInContext

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just putting Juraj's answer in code:

```
playerViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved me today. This was the exactly problem I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines will help you:

```
func createPlayer() -> AVPlayerViewController {
    let player = AVPlayerViewController()
    player.view.frame = viewFrame
    player.showsPlaybackControls = false
    player.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    return player
}
```

Comment: in other words settings any view isUserInteractionEnabled to false, will prevent focus engine to pick it.